# How can I pass php code as a content while publishing a post

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm parsing JSON data and want to display it in a Wordpress post. Here's the code that I would like to publish. Any idea how I can include this in wp_insert_post.

```
$url = "http://metaweather.com/api/location/2379574";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
$weather_sate=$json_data['consolidated_weather'][0][weather_state_name]
$temperature=$json_data['consolidated_weather'][0][the_temp]
```

Comment: Do you want to insert the data into a specific post(s)? OR do you want to create a new post using your json data?

Comment: @Ruvee I want to create a new post using the JSON data.